# mongo to linq pivot/unpivot data

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq, pivot, unpivot

I have a mongo collection like below:

date: "2022-03-09"

dryMinTemp: "12.14"

dryMaxTemp: "14.06"

wetMinTemp: "28.08"

wetMaxTemp: "12.14"

dryHour:    "02"

wetHour:    "14"

1.I need to represent data using c# Linq in below form:

**Type | Min | Max|    Hour**

Dry  | 12.14| 14.06|  02

Wet  | 28.08| 12.14|  14

I am new to both mongo and c#

2. there can be cases when we have 2 documents for one date, in that case max and min need to be added for same type, date and hour combination.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by making  separate lists using group by and then merging them together before showing the output.